# How to separate each group of five stars by a vertical line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, design-patterns

I'm a new one at the world of Python programming. I've just, unfortunately, stuck on this, I think, simple exercise.

So what I should do is to modify the stars(n) function to print n stars, with each group of five stars separated by a vertical line.
I have code like this, but I really don't know what to do with it.

```
def stars(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print("*", end='')
        if i == 4:
            print("|", end="")

    print()

stars(7)
stars(15)
```

The output should be like that:

```
*****|**
*****|*****|*****|
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this. One way could be to first calculate how many whole groups of 5 stars you have, and how many are left.

Comment: Where it says `if i == 4:` you may want to change that `== 4` for some condition that reflects multiples of 5. Tip: use the operator `%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the condition. This code should do:

```
def stars(n):
for i in range(n):
    print("*", end='')
    if i % 5 == 4:
        print("|", end="")

print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Trickier than expected...

```
def stars(n):
    solution = ''
    for i in range(n):
        if i % 5 == 0 and i != 0:
            solution += '|'
        solution += '*'

    if n % 5 == 0:
        solution += '|'

    return solution

print(stars(7))
print(stars(15))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code would look like this

```py
def stars(n):
    for i in range(n+1):
        if i%5 == 0:
            if i == 0:
                print("", end="")
            else:
                print("*|", end="")
        else:
            print("*", end='')

stars(7)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).